# How does url_for(@workshop) become "/workshops/5"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you call `url_for` on a model object:

```
<%= url_for(@workshop) %>
```

The [docs for `url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001596) say it calls `@workshop.to_s` which results in:

```
/workshops/5
```

*`But if I just call to_s on the model, I don't get the route`* - **how does url_for do this**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside ActionController it is calling a method called polymorphic_url.  Basically it inspects the type of Object that @workshop is and uses that plus its ID to construct the route.  So if @workshop.class = Workshop, rails can do a to_s.downcase on that and then start building the route based on the other url_for options and the action.  The code is in the module PolymorphicRoutes in the rails source.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe it does `@workshop.class.to_s.underscore` in case there are multiple words in the class name. For instance: UserRole.class.to_s.underscore = 'user_role'. Add on a `.pluralize` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough of ruby or rails to question the documentation but what is really happening is that it is calling `@workshop.id.to_s` to get the 5 (the id being the primary key in the database). To call straight Workshop.to_s will get you the memory reference of the object.

Comment: I think it actually calls #to_param on your object. That's what you can over-ride if you want the URL to feature an seo-friendly-url for example - or anything that isn't the record's id.